# OpenCV 2.4 for Android. Strange difference between Java and native code productivity

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk, computer-vision

Something like this, written on Java:

```
// ...preparing inputs
Imgproc.goodFeaturesToTrack(curImage, prevPts, NUM_OF_PTS, 0.001, 10);
// ...
Video.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(prevImage, curImage, prevPts2f, nextPts2f, status, err);
// ... visualization, Core.circle
```

Works a lot faster than this on C:

```
Mat* now=(Mat*)addrGray;
Mat* frame=(Mat*)addrRgba;
Mat* prev=(Mat*)addrPrevGray;

goodFeaturesToTrack( *now,
        vnew,
        maxCorners,
        qualityLevel,
        minDistance,
        Mat(),
        blockSize,
        useHarrisDetector,
        k );
for( size_t i = 0; i < vnew.size(); i++ ) {
    circle(*frame, Point(vnew[i].x, vnew[i].y), 10, Scalar(255,0,0,255));
}
calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(*prev, *now, vprev, vprevNow, status, track_error, winSize, maxLevel, tc, derivLambda,flags);
vprev.clear();
vector<Point2f>::iterator iter=vnew.begin();
while (iter != vnew.end()) {
    vprev.push_back(*iter);
    ++iter;
}
vnew.clear();
vprevNow.clear();
```

Why and how can I fix it? Or what is the better way to do it?

Comment: I believe Java side also makes use of native libraries so there must be something wrong with your setup. It can not be faster in Java since you basically call the same C function from Java.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is C. C is much faster than Java and you can't fix it. If you need fast perfomance use native code and NDK

Comment: Yes, and that's why it is strange... Because in my case code on C works a lot SLOWER than on Java (: